# Generation unique url after redirect Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i use this  code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';
}, false );
</script>
```

This code redirect me `https://www.example.com/thank-you/`

I want this redirect me `https://www.example.com/thank-you/fdsffdfggfh` (unique link everytime) but show me 
`https://www.example.com/thank-you/`  this page content.

I try this and this work

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            var length = 10;
            var res = '';
           var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
           var charLen = chars.length;
           for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
              res += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charLen));
           }
        location = 'http://example.com/thank-you/?'+res;
}, false );
```

thanks you @pagalprogrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by adding following code snippet on the target page:

```
function random_string(length) {
   var res = '';
   var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charLen = chars.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      res += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charLen));
   }
   return "/"+res;
}
window.history.pushState("", "", window.location.href+random_string(10));
```

You can also put some other random string function. This code make use of History API

Comment: that page already has its own url `https://www.example.com/thank-you/` and it page is save in page section  in wp-admin dashboard . and you need to assign another one to it, does it work out with your example? I just can't figure out how to put this together

Comment: I want to to go the https://www.example.com/thank-you/dsfsdf but show https://www.example.com/thank-you this content ... your code i put and it's send my email and doesnt redirect me , this code change url yes, but doesnt reditect

Comment: I see. Can you tell what you are doing with that last random part? or what you exactly want to do?

Comment: i try your before code. it's work , thanks , see my question , i update it . thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.example.com/thank-you/fdsffdfggfh` will end up in server routing. so you'll need to configure your server (nginx etc.) to redirect these requests to `https://www.example.com/thank-you`.

Another approch:
you can use query params - `https://www.example.com/thank-you?YOUR_KEY=fdsffdfggfh`
or hash `https://www.example.com/thank-you#fdsffdfggfh`

Comment: I did not understand you a little. I need the url to show  `https://www.example.com/thank-you/fdsffdfggfh`  and the content was this page `https://www.example.com/thank-you/`